# How to send proactive messages to MS teams in BOT v4

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to send some proactive messages to MS teams in BOT V4, however its not working.
Its ok in web chat and emulator but not working in MS Teams.

When i've put the code below to connect to MS teams, the proactive messages is now not working in Webchat and emulator as well.
The error message that i'm getting is:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ICredentialProvider' while attempting to activate 'Intelbot.Controllers.NotifyController'.
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you

```
**Notify controller.cs**
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Teams;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;



namespace Intelbot.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/notify")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NotifyController : ControllerBase
    {
        public static bool notifWhenStateChanges = false;
        public static bool notifWhenAboutToKo = false;
        public static bool notifNewTickets = true;
        public static bool leaaccessrequest = false;
        public static bool notifyCommentsForm = false;
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly string _appId;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;
        private readonly SimpleCredentialProvider _credentialProvider;
        public NotifyController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences, ICredentialProvider CredentialProvider)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
            _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
            _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"];
            _credentialProvider = CredentialProvider as ConfigurationCredentialProvider;
            // If the channel is the Emulator, and authentication is not in use,
            // the AppId will be null.  We generate a random AppId for this case only.
            // This is not required for production, since the AppId will have a value.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appId))
            {
                _appId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //if no AppId, use a random Guid
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
            {
                if (notifNewTickets == true)
                    await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));
            }
            // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
                ContentType = "text/html",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            };

        }


        private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl);
            var teamConversationData = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();
            var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), _credentialProvider.AppId, _credentialProvider.Password);

            var userId = "4534554654774412157657";
            var tenantId = teamConversationData.Tenant.Id;
            var parameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Members = new[] { new ChannelAccount(userId) },
                ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    Tenant = new TenantInfo(tenantId),
                },
            };

            var conversationResource = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters);
            var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            message.Text = "This is a proactive message1.";
            await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationResource.Id, (Activity)message);
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("proactive hello");
            if (notifNewTickets)
            {
                // var splunkItem = await SplunkService.GetSplunkInfo("notification", "newTickets","");
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("**ALERT! New Tickets**" + Environment.NewLine);
            }


        }
    }
}

startup.cs
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.
//
// Generated with Bot Builder V4 SDK Template for Visual Studio EchoBot v4.5.0

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams;
using Intelbot.Bots;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.Middlewares;
using Proactive;
using Proactive.Bots;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Intelbot.Controllers;

namespace Intelbot
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
            services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
            // Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.)
            services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();

            // Create the User state.
            services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

            // Create the Conversation state.
            services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

            // Create a global hashset for our ConversationReferences
            services.AddSingleton<ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference>>();

            var credentials = new SimpleCredentialProvider(Configuration["MicrosoftAppId"], Configuration["MicrosoftAppPassword"]);

            services.AddSingleton(credentials);

            // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
            services.AddBot<ProactiveBot>(options =>
            {
                options.CredentialProvider = credentials;

                options.Middleware.Add(
                    new TeamsMiddleware(
                        new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(this.Configuration)));

                // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
                services.AddTransient<IBot, EchoBot>();
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}

proactivebot.cs

// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.
//
// Generated with Bot Builder V4 SDK Template for Visual Studio EchoBot v4.3.0

// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;

namespace Intelbot.Bots
{
    public class ProactiveBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        // Message to send to users when the bot receives a Conversation Update event
        private const string WelcomeMessage = "Welcome to the Proactive Bot sample.  Navigate to http://localhost:3978/api/notify to proactively message everyone who has previously messaged this bot.";

        // Dependency injected dictionary for storing ConversationReference objects used in NotifyController to proactively message users
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;

        public ProactiveBot(ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
        {
            _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
        }

        private void AddConversationReference(Activity activity)
        {
            var conversationReference = activity.GetConversationReference();
            _conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(conversationReference.User.Id, conversationReference, (key, newValue) => conversationReference);
        }

        protected override Task OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            AddConversationReference(turnContext.Activity as Activity);

            return base.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(WelcomeMessage), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            AddConversationReference(turnContext.Activity as Activity);

            // Echo back what the user said
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"You sent '{turnContext.Activity.Text}'"), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As we've solved this portion, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If you don't believe this part is resolved, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is asking for the concrete class, `SimpleCredentialProvider`, when it should be asking for the interface `ICredentialProvider`,

Change:

```cs
public NotifyController(... SimpleCredentialProvider CredentialProvider)
```

To:

```cs
public NotifyController(... ICredentialProvider CredentialProvider)
[...]
_credentialProvider = CredentialProvider as ConfigurationCredentialProvider;
```

---

This assumes that you have this in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, ConfigurationCredentialProvider>();
```

If, instead, you have something more like this:

```cs
services.AddBot<LuisTranslatorBot>(options =>
{
    options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(endpointService.AppId, endpointService.AppPassword);
```

...you need to use:

```cs
ICredentialProvider credentialProvider
```

Comment: Hello Richardson, thanks a lot for your reply
i'm stucked on this since two weeks.

My startup.cs is like this:

``````````````````````````
services.AddBot<ProactiveBot>(opt =>
            {
var credentials = new SimpleCredentialProvider(Configuration["2c988176-cea6-4aaa-9a69-8ace544a43e3"], 

Configuration["Alberteinstein1234!"]);
               
opt.CredentialProvider = credentials;

                opt.Middleware.Add(
                new TeamsMiddleware(
                 new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(this.Configuration)));

            });

Comment: The error message that i'm getting is: 
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ICredentialProvider' while attempting to activate 'Intelbot.Controllers.NotifyController'.

I'm changing the code above in the problem statement to what you told me

Comment: @NivinSunathree If you're still experiencing this, can you either edit your question to include your current `Startup.cs` and `NotifyController`? Alternatively (and preferably), can you send a link to your full code?